# CakePHP: get domain (address) used to land in my page

Tags: cakephp, redirect, get, dns

This is what I need to do:

I'm creating a site in CakePHP where I need to show different stuff (logo, pictures, etc) depending on what **sub-domain** the user has used to get to my site. For example: let's say there are 3 sub-domains:

- subdomain1.mydomain.com
- subdomain2.mydomain.com
- subdomain3.mydomain.com

All three sub-domains will point to the same folder in the server where my CakePHP app is. I would like to know how can I get the sub-domain used by the user so I can show different things depending on that.

I don't know if this can affect my question, but there's one more thing. The users won't actually use the sub-domain links. They will use other domains that redirect to the sud-domains. For example, a user will enter www.whateverdomain1.com and he will be redirected to subdomain1.mydomain.com. However, I've been told that the user won't actually see the redirection, he will always see the www.whateversomain1.com that he used.

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think would be to have your webserver redirect requests from sub.domain.com to domain.com/sub, and from there using the route configuration.

In the route configuration - you have two options, either to use prefixes (http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Prefix-Routing-950) or setting up named parameters:

```
Router::connect(':subdomain/:controller/:action/:id', array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

And in your controllers you can then check via

```
$this->params
```

to see what the subdomain is and set your variables accordingly.